# Order status processing issue on successful payment from Paypal in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway

I am having strange issue and this happens sometimes, when user pay for a course via paypal the order status changed from pending to processing instead of completed.

In this image IPIN notification received but still order is in processing stage, what could causing this issue. I tried to replicate this issue but it does not replicated at my end, It happens sometimes.

[image]

Here is product info:

1. Product is virtual product
2. Stock is disabled

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are selling only virtual products, you can force order status to "completed" for Paypal on payment complete function, this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'paypal_payment_complete_order_status', 10, 2 );
function paypal_payment_complete_order_status( $status, $order_id, $order ){
    if( $order->get_payment_method() === 'paypal' )
        $status = 'completed';

    return $status;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

> This hook is only triggered on successful payment and has originally 2 possible order status values "processing" or "completed" *(depending if "processing" is required)*. So this answer code just force the order status to "completed" targeting Paypal payment gateway *(for virtual products)*. [This hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#122) is located on `WC_Order` [`payment_complete()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#90-139) method. 
>   All payment gateways use [`payment_complete()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#90-139) method on a successful payment and Paypal use it on [`WC_Gateway_Paypal_Response`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Gateway_Paypal_Response.html#_payment_complete) Class.

Comment: does it work because you check get_payment_method insted of order_status, in my case order status changes from pending to to processing but does not change to completed.

can it be like this:
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
if ( 'processing' == $order_status ) {

 return 'completed';

 }

Comment: @HemantKumar Yes it does, because this hook is only triggered on successful payment and has originally 2 possible order status values "processing or completed. So I just force "completed" status for Paypal payment. I hope that you understand better. So if you have only virtual products, this is the right hook for Paypal.